# AWS API Gateway, abort request in Browser

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, gateway, abort

So, I have an API in API GateWay being called from client's browser using the JavaScript API Client from AWS.

Now I want the client to be able to manually cancel a running request (e.g. a file upload) by clicking a button or similar.

Is there any known way of doing this?